# Qt's pragma directives

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, pragma

Could anyone point me out to an article, where pragma directives, available in Qt environment would be discussed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK `pragma` directives are preprocessor and compiler directives and have not much to do with Qt itself.

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html
- https://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-3-Manual/gcc/pragmas.html

Qt provides some *defines*, which can be used to do things like enable/disable parts of the source code depending on which platform you are compiling:

- http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtglobal.html

You can use them like this:

```
#ifdef Q_WS_MAC
  (some mac code goes here)
#endif

#ifdef Q_WS_WIN32
  (some windows code goes here)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete list of moduyles in Qt which can be removed by defines is found in src>corelib>global>qconfig-minimal.h in the folder of your original Qt download.